# How do I get my mouse-based input system to work on Android?

Tags: unity, c#

I am developing the ball breaker game in unity and right now my game work with mouse click button. but i want my game work in android. so what changes i want to do in this code? So when i set the arrow and its jump ball and hit the brick.
Here is the code with image :-

BallController.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallController : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum ballState {
        aim,
        fire,
        wait,
        endShot
    }

    public ballState currentBallState; 

    public Rigidbody2D ball;
    private Vector2 mouseStartPosition;
    private Vector2 mouseEndPosition;
    private float ballVelocityX;
    private float ballVelocityY;
    public float constantSpeed;
    public GameObject arrow; 


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        currentBallState = ballState.aim;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        switch (currentBallState) {
        case ballState.aim:
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                MouseClicked ();
            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
                MouseDragged ();

            }
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
                ReleaseMouse ();
            }
             break;

        case ballState.fire:

            break;

        case ballState.wait:

            break;

        case ballState.endShot:

            break;
        default:
            break;


        }



    }

    public void MouseClicked(){
        mouseStartPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.Log (mouseStartPosition);
        //didClick = true;
    }

    public void MouseDragged(){
    //  didDrag = true;
        //Move the Arrow 
        arrow.SetActive(true);
        Vector2 tempMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        float diffX = mouseStartPosition.x - tempMousePosition.x;
        float diffY = mouseStartPosition.y - tempMousePosition.y;
        if (diffY <= 0) {
            diffY = .01f;

        }
        float theta = Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan (diffX / diffY);
        arrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0f, 0f, -theta);
    }
    public void ReleaseMouse(){
        arrow.SetActive (false);
        mouseEndPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        ballVelocityX = (mouseStartPosition.x - mouseEndPosition.x);
        ballVelocityY = (mouseStartPosition.y - mouseEndPosition.y);
        Vector2 tempVelocity = new Vector2 (ballVelocityX, ballVelocityY).normalized;
        ball.velocity = constantSpeed * tempVelocity;
        if (ball.velocity == Vector2.zero) {
            return;
        }
        currentBallState = ballState.fire;

    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look this: [MobileInputUnity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html).
You must change the method for the touch alternative using the phase property of Input.touch:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {   //e.g. if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            MouseClicked ();
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {  //e.g. if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            MouseDragged ();

        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {  //e.g. if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            ReleaseMouse ();
        }
```

And there is a property for the postition too, so when you access to Input.mousePostion you only must change to Input.GetTouch(0).position.
If your game can use more than one finger, unless use Input.GetTouch(0), you must control all the touches, for example, with a for bucle:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
               // Some code ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently added native Mouse & Keyboard input support for Android & iOS / iPadOS. Works just like it does on PC.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/mobile-input-capture-221017

- InputCapture.GetMouseScroll()
- InputCapture.GetMouseVelocity()
- InputCapture GetMouseButton, GetMouseButtonDown, GetMouseButtonUp
- InputCapture GetKey, GetKeyDown, GetKeyUp
- InputCapture.isMouseCaptureSupported: check if device is supported
- InputCapture.isMouseCaptureEnabled: check if capture active

Comment: This is currently a link only answer, could you add more to it, e.g. how they would use it?

Comment: He is asking about Unity3D support for this feature. The plugin is fully documented.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many things are "fully documented" and yet still benefit from walkthroughs about how to use those documented features to accomplish specific goals. 

Comment: The plugin has code examples in the images from the link, it has example scenes, code & documentation. There isn't much to say. It just works as you would want / expect / hope it would. Regardless I've updated answer. There isn't much to say. It does just what the person is asking for. Comes with full source code too.